# Determine if item has own stock, i.e. is not a compound item and not virtual

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, stock

This seems like it should be straightforward but I cannot find a clean solution:

Given an order item, what's the best way to figure out if the item has its **own stock**?

First I load the stock item:

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
    ->loadByProduct($orderItem->getProductId());
```

Unfortunately, I get results for all items, and those from configurable products seem undistinguishable from simple products.

Then I thought of:

- checking the **product type**. This is my least favorite solution because we work a lot with custom product types. I would have to define every single case and change it when new types are added
- checking if item is a **parent item**. Possible but there is only `getParentItem()` so I'd have to go through all items, collect the parent item ids and remove those items.

For a generic solution it would be great to cover virtual products as well but for my use case it is not relevant. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nobody comes up with a better solution, this is what works for me:

```
$hasStock = ! $orderItem->getIsVirtual() && count($orderItem->getChildrenItems()) === 0
```

And to get all real stock items for an order `$order`:

```
$stockItems = [];
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $item */
    if ($item->getIsVirtual()) {
        continue;
    }
    if ($children = $item->getChildrenItems()) {
        foreach ($children as $childItem) {
            /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $childItem */
            if ($childItem->getIsVirtual()) {
                continue;
            }
            $stockItems[] = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                                ->loadByProduct($childItem->getProductId());
        }
    } else {
        $stockItems[] = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                            ->loadByProduct($item->getProductId());
    }
}
```